# Entries in .java.policy ignored

Tags: java, security, applet

I'm developing a JAVA Applet that requires read and write access to a folder. When I add the following entry into the java.policy file within the JRE folder it works:

```
 permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.home}${/}logtest${/}-", "read, write";
```

However if I add the entry in the .java.policy file within the users home directory it does not work.

Investigating further I add another policy file mytest.policy containing the exact same permission above and modified java.security file with:

```
policy.url.1=file:${java.home}/lib/security/java.policy
policy.url.2=file:${user.home}/.java.policy
policy.url.3=file:${user.home}/mytest.policy
```

The permissions are successfully applied.

Does anyone know why .java.policy permission entries don't work?

Comment: *"Does anyone know why .java.policy permission entries don't work?"* I'm having trouble caring why policy files are being ignored. After all.. *"I'm developing a JAVA Applet.."* the applet will need to be digitally signed before deployment to others, so why not start now? BTW: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: @AndrewThompson The project that I am working on requires an Applet, I am aware that Applets are on the way out. The applet has been signed (self signed) but this still does not work for so I'm also using policy files. Still the question remains why the .java.policy file permissions don't work but do work if the same entries are added to either the java.policy or a custom policy file.

Comment: *"The applet has been signed (self signed) .."* The JRE won't accept self-sined certificates any longer. They aren't worth the bits they're written on.

Comment: @AndrewThompson OK that's a good point regarding the self signed certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit file
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties
and add to file next line:
deployment.security.use.user.home.java.policy=true